# Regex: How to put into brackets every three words from many lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to put into brackets every three words from many line.

For example:

`word_1 word_2 word_3 word_4 word_5 word_6 word_7 word_8 word_9`

The desire result:

`(word_1 word_2 word_3) (word_4 word_5 word_6) (word_7 word_8 word_9)`

I try this regex, but doesn't work `^.*\w+\w+\w+.*$` Replace by `(\1) (\2) (\3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+
```

and replace with `\($0\)` where `$0` is the backreference to the whole match value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2fCFIL/1)

Note that `\w+` matches 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`) and `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces.

You must escape the parentheses in the replacement because Notepad++ uses Boost conditional replacement patterns where `(` and `)` are special operators.

[image]

Comment: It is because NPP uses Boost conditional replacement patterns, you need to escape `(` and `)` in the replacement there.